# Powershell write to a CSV while it's open

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have a process that will be running essentially 24/7. It will be writing data to a CSV but I want to be able to read that CSV periodically. The problem is that it seems like Export-Csv fails even when the file is opened in read only mode.

The CSV file in question is already marked as Read-Only so all writes I make to it in my script are using the force switch. This works fine but the second I open the file in excel (or even view it's properties in Windows Explorer) the script starts erroring out.

All I want to do is be able to do is write to a CSV with export-csv while also allowing that csv to be opened by excel in read only mode. Is this possible or do I need to come up with some method where I create a secondary copy of the file for viewing purposes?

Comment: I don't believe it possible due to MS locking the file. If you share the workbook it might work. However, you can not not share a csv. I would look more towards a DB solution, like SQLite

Comment: How do you open the file in excel? Manually? via a script?

Comment: I checked read-only in the properties and was able to update the csv while it was open in read-only mode, using the force switch.

Comment: Another thought, if the CSV isn't constantly open, you could use `System.IO.FileInfo` to check to see if the CSV is open. If so, wait for it to close before continuing.

Comment: I haven't verified, but it wouldn't surprise me if an application could have a read-write lock on a file marked as read-only. The filesystem would only block an attempt to save later. I'd guess opening the file in Excel, Wordpad ++ will cause you problems, while having it opened in notepad or PowerShell (using [System.IO.File] and read-only permission) would work fine due to the way their code opens the file

Comment: @zdan I'm opening the CSV manually (in excel since that's set as my default csv handler). With that said, I noticed that even when simply right clicking the file to view it's properties in explorer, the script will start throwing file lock related errors

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 You should write that up as an answer. I just tested it and it's like you said, I can open the CSV in notepad and the script continues without issue.Seems like the issue is on Excel's end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office suite has the tendency to lock files it opens (I'm making this assumption because you're working with a CSV).  If you open your file in `notepad.exe`, the problem you're experiencing will no longer happen.

Comment: Thanks. After testing your suggestion I can confirm that opening the csv with notepad, VS Code and other apps the issue did not produce the same issue. It seems like the problem was Excel not properly respecting the read only attribute and opening the file in a way that was locking it.